# Achieving a square imageview content for TableLayout with stretchColumns

Tags: android, android-layout

currently I'm currently trying to achieve a squared ImageViews inside a TableRows which is supposed to be squared even if the columns are stretched but unfortunately it doesn't work the way I expected it to be. The plan is pretty simple. Use a TableLayout to host a number of ImageViews but make those imageviews squared inside even if the it is stretched. Here's what I tried so far.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img3"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img2"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img4"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img6"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img5"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img6"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img6" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img6"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img4"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img4"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="true" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I expect the image to fill the width and height on those imageViews to create squared images based on my original image using this code:

```
private Bitmap sliceImage(int my_img, int col, int row) {
        /*send the original full image int id here then slice and return per icon*/
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), my_img);

        int width = icon.getWidth();
        int height = icon.getHeight();

        int crop_width = width / 3;
        int crop_height = height / 3;

        Bitmap test = Bitmap.createBitmap(icon, col * crop_width, row * crop_height, crop_width, crop_height);

        return test;
    }
```

and this to set:

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
img1.setImageBitmap(sliceImage(R.drawable.my_img,0,0));
```

and so on. But the the image is just stretched on its width but the height is not adjusted.

For sample it looks like this:

[image]

Where it should be more like this but stretched in both width and height:

[image]

Comment: post the snapshot of your problem.

Comment: added the images. :)